# Azure Logic App: passing JWT token

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm looking to have an async workflow, which looks like this:

- Azure API App sends message to Azure ServiceBus Topic
- receive message on Azure LogicApp ServiceBus connector
- call into different Azure API App endpoint

Optimally, I want to flow a JWT token through this workflow, so we can maintain authorization from the original API App, into the async-called endpoint.

Are there any models for passing JWT tokens through the Logic App connectors, to maintain authorization?  Or would this have to be hacked together?

Thanks,
Kirk

Comment: why am i not able to add a bounty to this question? it was asked in 2015